# Transform image using XAML and generate new image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, xaml, xamlreader

I have a ASP.NET MVC website.

I have a "flat" PNG image in my project that I need to transform. I think that I can use XAML for it.

Steps :

- Create a XAML UserControl (or other) that transform the image adding a 3d effect for example
- Use a XamlReader in my website controller, passing my flat image in parameter
- Generate the new image file with my 3d effect

Is it possible to do what I need ?

Are the steps correct ?

I didn't find a good tutorial to do it, so ifyou have one, thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly would you render your XAML in the webpage? By my knowledge you need Silverlight for that.

Comment: Hmm ok, sorry if the question was stupid. Someone told me that I could do it like this. In fact I have a WPF application with a WebBrowser that load the website. So it could be possible possible but a bit complciated... I thought I could do that directly from a asp.net mvc controller. I'll look for a javascript approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the javascript aproach?

for example http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/

and http://www.greensock.com/css3/